# What exactly is a "binary file"?

Tags: filesystems, storage, binary

I suspect this may be more of a concept / theory question, but, I haven't been able to wrap my brain around what exactly a binary file is.

I've read links such as the below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-little-diddy-about-binary-file-formats/

But, the piece of the puzzle that's confusing me, is that ALL files are stored as 1's and 0's on a hard-disk, or, in RAM, etc.
(i.e. there's no physical engraving of the hex characters "6F" onto a disk platter for example; it's still a binary format that the data is stored in).

So, if all files are stored as binary, then, presumably it's an operating-system, (& filesystem) concept to refer to something as "binary" file?

Comment: A binary file is one which is not a text file. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) for more on text files.

Answer (score -1):

A binary file is a file that is simply **not** a text file. It means that a bin file has a **specific format** (mp3, exe, jpg...) and can not be interpreted only as a character sequence. There are many ways data can be formatted and read.

Comment: A binary file need not have a "specific format".

Comment: A binary file is not just a bunch of 0's and 1's, it needs a way to be formatted.

Comment: If you store a cryptographic key in a file, it's not formatted at all. There isn't any set of allowable formats for files, dictated by the operating system.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. It's clearer this way